# How does the Air BnB achieve the user menu?

Tags: ios, uikit

Using the air bnb app, if you click on the far right icon on the tab menu, it opens a user menu which slides in from the right over the top but only takes up half of the screen. The rest of the screen below is dimmed.

How can this be implemented? Does it require a custom segue or view controller container?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar feature to what your describing done before using a modal segue that instantiates a new view with a partially transparent background. You have given a vague question so I can't really provide a specific answer. Comment if you need more info.

[Here is the app I saw it in, from a tutorial.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMxqS.png)